# .htaccess: Condition on HTTP_USER_AGENT then rewrite with dynamic subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm creating a static webpage solution for my angularJS project where I check for the HTTP_USER_AGENT in my .htaccess file and then redirect any crawlers to a static php page so I can add all the necessary meta data.

The problem is that I'm using a wildcard subdomain, so any of my clients can have their own subdomain and I can't figure out how to redirect via `RewriteRule` to the right url.

My `RewriteCond`looks like this:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Facebot|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)`

and my basic non-working `RewriteRule` looks like this:
`RewriteRule ^stuff/(.*)$ http://example.com/static.php?token=$1 [NC,L]`

But I want it to go to `static.php` on that subdomain the request is on, so if I request `http://subdomain.example.com/stuff?token=my-token` is it possible to make the rewriterule go to `http://subdomain.example.com/static.php?token=$1` instead of just the static `mydomain.com` above?
(there will NEVER be a request on http://example.com/stuff - all requests to `stuff` will be via a subdomain)

I'm not that experienced in .htaccess and get's a bit confused from all the answer that here listed at SO and Google finds.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding together pieces of code and a little bit of thinking.

This is the three lines in my `.htaccess` which does the trick for me:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Facebot|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ http://%1.sociuu.com/static.php?token=$1 [NC,L]`

If this can be done more elegant or smarter, please let me know otherwise I'll consider this as suitable for my needs :-)